# Find matches in NSDate array - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsdate, match, date-manipulation

I’m a newbie at both Swift (and coding in general) and stack overflow. SO has been tremendously helpful in learning how to code, so, countless thanks to the SO community for great questions and answers.

Here goes my first ever SO question…

I’ve been spinning my wheels for couple of days now on this challenge. I’ve read and tried multiple suggested solutions but none of them have worked for me so far.

I have a dynamic NSDate array that is retrieved from a web API (using earlier code).

```
[2016-05-01 03:27:22 +0000, 2016-05-01 03:27:24 +0000, 2016-05-01 03:27:25 +0000, 2016-05-01 03:27:27 +0000, 2016-05-03 12:48:07 +0000, 2016-05-03 12:48:09 +0000, 2016-05-03 12:48:11 +0000, 2016-05-03 12:48:13 +0000, 2016-05-03 19:52:46 +0000, 2016-05-03 19:52:51 +0000, 2016-05-03 19:52:56 +0000, 2016-05-04 00:37:27 +0000, 2016-05-04 00:37:30 +0000, 2016-05-04 12:36:17 +0000, 2016-05-04 12:36:19 +0000, 2016-05-04 12:46:26 +0000, 2016-05-04 12:46:28 +0000, 2016-05-04 17:39:31 +0000, 2016-05-04 17:39:34 +0000, 2016-05-04 17:54:24 +0000, 2016-05-04 23:46:20 +0000]
```

I set up a method that loops through the above array and checks to see if there are any items in the array that are timestamped within the last x minutes.

```
    func prepareJSONData1 () {

    let currentDate = NSDate()
    var startDate = currentDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-5 * 60) //sets the start date to 5 minutes prior to current time


    while startDate.compare(currentDate) != NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending  {

        var i = Int(0) //setting up a counter

        for i in 0...self.quantumArrayNSDate.count - 1 {

            if startDate == self.quantumArrayNSDate[i] {
                print("Data entry found for \(startDate) timestamp")
            }
            self.i += 1
        }

        startDate = startDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(1) //increment through the NSDate range

    }
}
```

I can't get this code to return matching items no matter how far back I set the start date (even if I go back a couple of months). I suspect that I'm not setting the startDate variable correctly, because if I change that piece of code to:

```
startDate = quantumArrayNSDate.first!
```

Then the code returns all items in the array as I would expect it to.

I've also tried this other approach without any success:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let startDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Minute, value: -5, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])!     // <- this didn't work
```

I would be super grateful if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong and propose a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSDate` represents  a point in time, and is stored as the time interval
in seconds since the reference date January 1, 2001, UTC. This time interval is a floating point number (`NSTimeInterval` aka `Double`)
and includes fractional seconds as well. So two `NSDate`s
created within the same second can be different:

```
let date1 = NSDate()
let date2 = NSDate()
print(date1 == date2)
// false
print(date2.timeIntervalSinceDate(date1))
// 5.00679016113281e-06
```

Your test for equality

```
if startDate == self.quantumArrayNSDate[i]
```

fails unless both dates represent exactly the same point in time up to 
fractional second precision.

You can iterate over the dates within the given time interval
with

```
for date in quantumArrayNSDate {
    if date.compare(startDate) == .OrderedDescending
     && date.compare(currentDate) == .OrderedAscending {
        // ... 
    }
}
```

or get a list of matching dates with

```
let filteredDates = quantumArrayNSDate.filter { date in
    date.compare(startDate) == .OrderedDescending
        && date.compare(currentDate) == .OrderedAscending
}
```

To check if two dates are equal up to second granularity, you can use

```
if calendar.compareDate(date, toDate: currentDate, toUnitGranularity: .Second) == .OrderedSame {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Martin. Worked like a charm!